# Minimize on click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a notification block at the lower right end of my webpage which is fixed. I have designed it using HTML and CSS. Here is the link.. http://jsfiddle.net/wp5Lfjwq/

Now if the user click's on 'X', I want the notification to get resized (say for example, height: 50px and width: 50px) and only show the 'Some Title' and do not want the whole notification box to disappear.

By using toggle in java-script I can make it disappear but how do I resize it?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="notification">
  <span class="notificationtitle">
    <strong>Some Title</strong>
    <span style="float: right">X</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.notification {
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid solid none;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 2px 2px medium;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #666;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  height: 190px;
  text-align: center;
}


.notificationtitle {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 26px;
  font: "HelveticaNeueLTStd65Medium";
  color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Where is javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Answer is ...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".show span").click(function() {
   $(".show").css( 'display' , 'none' );
   $(".hide").css( 'display' , 'block' );
  });
  $(".hide strong").click(function() {
   $(".hide").css( 'display' , 'none' );
   $(".show").css( 'display' , 'block' );
  });
    });
```

```css
.notification {
 border-image: none;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 2px 2px medium;
    padding: 10px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border-color: #666;
 right: 10px;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 300px;
 float: left;
 height: 190px;
 text-align: center;
}
.show{
 display:block;
}
.hide{
 display:none;
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.notificationtitle {
 display: block;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 26px;
 font: "HelveticaNeueLTStd65Medium";
 color: #4d4d4d;
}
.notificationtitle span{
 float:right;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notification show">
        <span class="notificationtitle"><strong>Some Title</strong><span>X</span></span>
</div>
<div class="notification hide">
  <span class="notificationtitle"><strong>Some Title</strong></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to any else Questions

Answer (score 0):

## Use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('.notificationtitle').on('click',function(){
    $('.notification').animate({width:'50px',height:'46px'});
})
```

## [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wp5Lfjwq/9/)

Comment: Thank you Manwal. The code is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('.notificationtitle span').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.notification').css({width:'50px',height:'50px'});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wp5Lfjwq/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/wp5Lfjwq/11/

toggle a `class` with `width` and `height`

```js
$('.notificationtitle').on('click', function () {
    $('.notification').toggleClass('hide');
})
```

```css
.notification {
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 2px 2px medium;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #666;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 190px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}
.notificationtitle {
    display: block;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 26px;
    font:"HelveticaNeueLTStd65Medium";
    color: #4d4d4d;
}
.hide {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notification"> <span class="notificationtitle"><strong>Some Title</strong><span style="float: right">X</span></span>
</div>
```